# Are Snitches protected from the Accio Charm?

Tags: harry-potter

Since Quidditch players are allowed wands, as evidenced when Harry used the Patronus Charm in Prisoner of Azkaban to fend off 100+ dementors, does that imply that they can use Accio to summon the Snitch? Or did Dumbledore or Madam Hooch see this problem through and placed the Snitch under an Anti-Theft Charm so as to prevent the capturing of the Snitch so easily?

Comment: Uh what? Where does he fend off 100+ dementors? He uses his wand to defend against three *fake* dementors in the middle of a game, but...

Comment: @Mithrandir I meant 3. Here's a quote from PoA "Three dementors, three tall, black, hooded dementors, were looking up at him.
He didn't stop to think. Plunging a hand down the neck of his robes, he whipped out his wand and roared, "Expecto patronum!"
Something silver-white, something enormous, erupted from the end of his wand. He knew it had shot directly at the dementors but didn't pause to watch; his mind still miraculously clear, he looked ahead -- he was
nearly there.

Comment: Yes. So... Why did you write 100+ when it was three fake ones? O_o

Comment: @Mithrandir because I forgot how what the exact quote was, but they weren't FAKE

Comment: What do you mean? The dementors in this case were the Slytherins dressed up.

Comment: @Mithrandir How when it was a Ravenclaw-Gryffindor game? And you can't fly without a broom (only Voldie and Snape could).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57166/discussion-between-mithrandir-and-kyle-v).

Comment: Even if you don't believe the dementors in question weren't real dementors, please at least fix the question with respect to the number.

Comment: I thought there were hundreds of them at one qudditch game that caused Harry to pass out. Why do I have a memory of this number too? He didn't "fend them off" though.

Comment: @syntonicC Could be getting mixed up with the Quidditch World Cup incident?

Comment: @KyleV Here's another quote: " “The dementors didn’t affect me at all!” Harry said excitedly.
“That would be because they — er — weren’t dementors,” said
Professor Lupin. “Come and see —”
He led Harry out of the crowd until they were able to see the
edge of the field.
“You gave Mr. Malfoy quite a fright,” said Lupin.
Harry stared. Lying in a crumpled heap on the ground were
Malfoy, Crabbe, Goyle, and Marcus Flint, the Slytherin team Captain, all struggling to remove themselves from long, black, hooded
robes. It looked as though Malfoy had been standing on Goyle’s
shoulders. "

Comment: The hundreds of dementors thing was at the end of PoA, where Pettigrew had just escaped, Professor Lupin was in werewolf form, and Harry and Hermione were using the Time-Turner to save Buckbeak and Sirius.

Answer (score 20):

The rules of Quidditch clearly state that wanded magic must not be used on the balls.

> *Players may take their wands onto the pitch, but they must not be used
> on or against any players, any players' broomsticks, the referee, any
> of the four balls, or the spectators.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Quidditch through the Ages](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quidditch_Through_the_Ages)</sup></sub>

Given the temptation to cheat and the [trivial ease with which an "anti-accio" spell can be cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54594/why-couldnt-luna-do-accio-shoes), it's reasonable to assume that the Snitch is also proofed against simple summoning charms, even if it **wasn't already an immediate forfeit** to cheat by summoning it.

Comment: If you count the Dementors as spectators then Harry definitely broke the rules.

Comment: @Pharap No, they are the specters.